# PHP/MySQL: Storing Entry Names/Languages Separately Or Deliminated?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that will contain the name of books.  This table will contain the title in various languages including English, Spanish, French, German, Japanese, Romaji.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to store this information and have come up with two options.

Option A - Multiple Columns:
Quite simply, a column for each, such as..
id, title_en, title_sp, title_fr, title_de, title_ja, title_ro

Option B - One Column:
The other would be to store all names in ONE column, such as..
id, title
1, en:Example Book Title;sp:Ejemplo de título de libro
Option B would then be pulled with a SQL query and split with php using explode().

Not ALL these books will have titles in various languages.  In fact, most of them will have half or less of the supported languages.  That being said, if option A is used, a null/empty value will be in a lot of the entries.

Option A requires pulling info, half of which is empty/null.
Option B pulls one column vs many, and processes it via PHP.

Both options work great but I guess my bigger question is... at scale, would pulling a ton of empty/null entries cost unnecessary cycles compared to just pulling one column and splitting it in PHP?  Or would there really be no obvious difference?  The only real advantage I can see in Option A is if I wanted to search by exact title.

Edit: For context, there will be 10K+ entries and the various language titles are to show the alternate titles.  Normalizing the DB does seem to make sense as mentioned in comments, and should pull up fine when properly querying.  I got so used to always having a title/name in a table, I was overthinking what to do if there were multiple titles/names.

Comment: Books table. Languages table. Names table which refers to previous tables.

Comment: Multiple columns are bad when you add a new language, several values in the same column make it difficult to query.

Comment: You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. If you design your database properly (keeping things separated), I don't see why you would be "pulling a ton of empty/null entries". You fetch what you need, when you need it. Databases are excellent at what they do, as long as you use them correctly.

Comment: @M. Eriksson yea you make a good point, I appreciate the feedback.  My brain was so used to thinking the row should contain a title/name for entries such as this, I was overthinking something simple.